# Is it possible to catch native calls in a Background Mode?

Tags: ios, pushkit

Is it possible to catch native/cellular calls while the app is running in the background (with a background mode like e.g. Bluetooth LE) via PushKit/Callkit?

My research so far only came to the solution that you can register on Voip-Calls trough a certain socket while running with the respective Voip-Background-Mode.

Comment: No. The voip mode you're discussing has nothing to do with cellular calls, and CallKit can't be used this way.

Comment: by "this way" you mean in background mode? Since CallKit in general is able to catch cellular calls.

Comment: I'm not aware of the feature you're describing. CallKit can provide extensions for directory and call blocking, but that's done as an extension, not an app. Perhaps I misunderstand what you mean by "catch." What is your app currently doing in the foreground to "catch native/cellular class?"